# UIActivityViewController is not working in iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiactivityviewcontroller, xcode9

I am using UIActivityViewController to share a article url, using the below code,

```
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:shareItemArray applicationActivities:nil];

activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll, UIActivityTypeAirDrop]; 

[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The above code working in iOS 9 & 10, but it is not working in iOS 11

I debugged it, the code is executing fine, after that i am getting a error log in console like below

[ShareSheet] ERROR:  timed out waiting to establish a connection to the ShareUI view service extension.

Is there any people facing this problem? Is there a workaround?

EDIT: After clean and run the project, i tried to do the same, after 2 or 3 times the UIActivityViewController got opened, again i tried, for the first time i am getting the same above error, second time only the UIActivityViewController is getting opened.

Comment: clean and run once, are you sure u faced the issue of `timed out waiting to establish a connection to the ShareUI view service extension.` of this after used the `UIActivityViewController`

Comment: can you show the `shareItemArray`

Comment: clean and runned it bro, i got the same timed out error 2 or 3 times, after that uiactivityviewcontroller is opening now.

Comment: In that shareItemArray i am having the below NSUrl only "http://www.60secondsnow.com/ta/tamil-nadu/opening-water-from-mullaperiyar-dam-627610.html"

Comment: i think is the problem is somewhere else

Comment: i tried https://github.com/versluis/Activity-Demo this project too in iOS 11, in that project also i got the same issue. After that only i posted this question.

Comment: ok i wil check this

Comment: Can anyone clarify why the error is logged, but the UI simply appears to not respond? Assuming you want to keep it in the main thread, is there something missing, that would trap the error?

Comment: @benc just add the code into the main thread as per the answer, it will work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All code that modifies the user interface needs to be run in the main queue, that's by design. So all you need to do is this:

```
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:shareItemArray applicationActivities:nil];

activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll, UIActivityTypeAirDrop]; 

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
});
```

A little more explanation: `dispatch_async()` will enqueue the block you pass to it to run in a near future when it will be safe to update the UI. If you don't do that on the main queue, weird things can happen (sometimes the UI simply doesn't change, or old changes can be applied after newer ones, or stuff like that).

Methods that are messaged from user actions in the UI (for example, in `IBAction` when you tap a button) already run on the main queue, so `dispatch_async()` is not necessary there (of course, assuming you're not calling those `IBAction`s manually from another queue).

Note that `alloc`/`init` and `setExcludedActivityTypes:` don't update the UI, so there's no need to call those on the main queue.

Comment: Hey @Alejandro Iván I'm getting crash when open shareing view and getting this error in log,
 <UIActivityViewController: 0x7fb80406ce00> timed out waiting to establish a connection to the ShareUI view service extension. Can you please help here?

Comment: @SamkitShah I have no idea, I would assume some system-level services are failing. Try rebooting your device (Power+Home on iPhone 6s or fewer, Power+VolumeDown on iPhone 7 or newer, let the buttons go when you see the Apple startup logo).

Answer (score 8):

For swift 4.0

```
let activityViewController: UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [shareItem], applicationActivities:nil)
activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [.print, .copyToPasteboard, .assignToContact, .saveToCameraRoll, .airDrop]

DispatchQueue.main.async {
   self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:shareItemArray applicationActivities:nil];

         activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll, UIActivityTypeAirDrop]; 
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
               [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
         });
    });
```

I had same problem, but in Swift3 and it works fine.

Comment: Double main queue? What for? Only `presentViewController:animated:completion:` is required to be called in the main queue.

Comment: Oh yeah man, you're correct. In my case, I have a HUD animation and to works fine I need double queue. Do you have another solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I was with the same problem, and I figured out that I was not calling in UI Thread. Try to run in UI Thread and see if fix the problem